# How to create a widget with a list of content parts in Orchard?

Tags: c#, content-management-system, orchardcms

I'm working on a little Orchard CMS project and want to create a Widget to include in my Pages, from which I can add or remove items. Each of these items is a Product (small content part that displays a name, picture and short description for the item).

This Widget I want to create, should be able to add or delete products from it, without maximum or minimum limitations.

Then, how can I (in a programmatic way) create this content part that will have a collection (to put it in a way) of products?

Comment: Any reason why you want it programmatically when Orchard supports it ootb? You can just create a new widget content type and attach a contentpickerfield to it. Configure it for selecting products only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is semantics. A widget in Orchard is a type and it is to be used embedded in Layers

You can easily do it programatically by attaching the a part (your widget) to any other ContentItem in the part's handler.

It can be done in Migrations too and if you check the latest version 1.9x, check the Layouts feature, using an Element (you can wrap your part in it) which seems to me would be the best choice here, since it gives you more control over which "pages" should contain these products. 
In Layouts there is a Projection Element now, so that could help too.

There is always looking at the source. I have learnt lots from other people modules.